# Accessing parent by a standard controller

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

I have page which uses contact standard controller which is as below

```
<apex:page standardController="contact">
    {!contact.account.name}
</apex:page>
```

When I pass a valid id for contact it displays related account name, without any error.

In the Salesforce quickstart documentation for Displaying Field Values with Visualforce:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm

> Note: You cannot access parent objects using this expression language. In other words, {!account.parent.name} will return an error.

As per this, my code was supposed to throw an error. Why that did not happen?

Comment: You aren't very clear as to what you are asking.  Are you saying that you get that error, or are you asking why you aren't getting that error?

Comment: edited query ..hope its more clear now

Comment: I don't see anything in that document that says it should throw an error.  It makes sense that what you are putting in there could work.

Comment: ok..so then what does this mean by?You cannot access parent objects using this expression language. In other words, {!account.parent.name} will return an error.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I do see it now.  I searched for it before and didn't see it.  Maybe they updated how it works, and just never updated documentation.

Comment: its there in the first note

Comment: I tested this just now.  It works for me.    I'd say the documentation needs updating.

Comment: More to the point, Visualforce has supported this syntax for many releases, so I ponder when this verbiage made it into the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I've confirmed that the code works as described.  sfdcfox notes that this syntax has worked for many releases.  I'd say the answer is that the documentation has not been updated.

Comment: Someone should report the inaccuracy using the feedback widget at the bottom of the documentation page. (if they haven't already)