# Can you display fields from parent record when creating/editing record in visualforce page using a standard controller (only)

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

**What I want to do**

I thought this would be easy, but it didn't work.  In researching, I found two conflicting sources of truth, so posting the question here.

I am using a simple visualforce page to create a child record from the parent record in master-detail relationship.

I have overrode the new button to use this visualforce page.

I want to display a few fields from the parent record on the new page of the child record (just for user to view, not to be editable)

**What I've Tried**

I tried using dot notation to pull in the field, using the `inputfield`, `outputfield`, and `outputtext` tags, but none of those displayed a value.

I also tried assigning to variable, and displaying the variable using `outputtext`, but that also displayed nothing.

I also tried using a formula field on the child object, but that also displayed blank.

Interestingly, editing the 'mini page layout' of the parent allows me to display parent fields in the pop-up on rollover (as I have set the parent field on the VF page to outputText.  If set to inputText it just appears as a lookup and no rollover possible).

[image: webupdate vf page w rollover]

Sample code for vf page, using outputfield, and outputtext + variable below

```
<apex:page standardController="Web_Profile_Update__c" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Recent_Update__c}"></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Recent_Update__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Ready_to_Publish__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Web_Profile__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Web_Profile__r.Name__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Fellow_Name__c}"/>
<!-- tried assigning to variable below
        <apex:variable value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Web_Profile__r.Name__c}" var="fellowname"/>
         <apex:outputText value="{!fellowname}"></apex:outputText>
-->        
    </apex:pageBlockSection>        
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**What the documentation says**:

[this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_display_field_values.htm) on developer.salesforce.com indicates that this is not possible

> You cannot access parent objects using this expression language. In other words, {!account.parent.name} will return an error.

However, [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller) on developer.salesforce.com, which is excerpted from visualforce in practice book and is specifically about the Standard Controller, says it is possible

> Fields on related parent sObjects, (whether a lookup or master-detail relationship,) can also be referenced and bound:

So...am I doing something wrong, or is this in fact not possible using just a standard controller?

Comment: I'm assuming, web profile update is child and web profile is parent. The page standard controller is on child. So you should refere the parent to get the parent record values, <apex:outputLabel value="{!Web_Profile_Update__c.Web_Profile__r.Recent_Update__c}"></apex:outputLabel>

Comment: Yes web profile update is child, and web profile is parent.  The example where I'm pulling a parent field does refer to the parent using dot notation: Web_Profile_Update__c.Web_Profile__r.Name__c

Comment: I think you should query the records from controller and access them from the page

Comment: Thanks - but the point of the question is whether this can be done w/ a standard controller only, without writing an extension or a custom controller to do this.

Comment: What is the url you are passing to the page?

Comment: @cropredy i have not customized the URL at all - just overridden the 'new' button on the object to point to the VF page.  The URL looks like: https://c.cs8.visual.force.com/apex/webUpdates?CF00NL0000003fDyh=1014&CF00NL0000003fDyh_lkid=a8xL000000007IM&scontrolCaching=1&retURL=%2Fa8xL000000007IM&sfdc.override=1

Comment: @gorav - If this is a VF page that is overriding the New button, you will only be able to display records from a parent page if the new button was click on the related list of the parent record. If it was then you can query / display the fields you need on your VF page. BUT you CANNOT do it with a standard controller only. You could try a formula field but since the record in not committed yet I do not believe the formulas will resolve yet

Comment: Thanks @eric, I hould have clarified the new button is being clicked from related list on parent. Sounds like I need an extension. Edited to reflect that I tried formula field and it doesn't work. Marginally interesting that the rollover when setting the parent look up to outputfield does work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing parent by a standard controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36614/accessing-parent-by-a-standard-controller)